# Does Surprise Spell only work if the target doesn't see the spell coming?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, prestige-class, sneak-attack

I was researching sneak attacks made with spells and came across [an interesting answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/45524/23058). That answer says the Arcane Trickster 10th level ability Surprise Spells lets you deal sneak attack damage with any spell, and goes on to name fireball.

How would sneak attacking via Surprise Spells apply to spells that the target can easily see, like [black tentacles](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/black-tentacles/)? Do the Arcane Trickster's spells benefit from their targets being flatfooted as long as the caster is invisible, or does the spell existing and being visible prevent the spell being used to sneak attack since they can see it to react?

Comment: Related [OOTS comic](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0020.html)... ouch.

Comment: Remember, “[thing] and [thing]” is not a good title.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie your editted title made the already posted answer rather off-place. I think *"Does Surprise Spell work with indirect damage spells [like black tentacles] if the caster's situation allows it to a direct-damage one?"* fits the spirit of OP's original question better.

Comment: @Mindwin Sure, that would be an accurate edit if you wanted to make it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## A surprise spell must be a [targeted](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) spell

The [arcane trickster](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/prestigeClasses/arcaneTrickster.html) special ability surprise spells, in part, says, "At 10th level, an arcane trickster can add her sneak attack damage to any spell that deals damage, if the targets are flat-footed." Unlike, for example, the spell [*magic missile*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-missile/) that has the entry *Targets: Up to five creatures, no two of which can be more than 15 ft. apart*, the spells [*black tentacles*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/black-tentacles/) and [*fireball*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball/) have no *Target* entries so they have *no* targets (and, in fact, most area spells don't). [Employing a targeted spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) is one of the requirements for the special ability surprise spells to trigger.

### Being [invisible](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#invisible) doesn't make your foes [flat-footed](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#flat-footed)

Merely being [invisible](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#invisible) is insufficient to render a foe [flat-footed](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#flat-footed) against the invisible creature's attacks. The invisible attacking creature *does* gain a +2 bonus on its attack rolls and the foe *does* lose it's Dexterity bonus to AC against the attack, but the foe is not actually considered flat-footed against attacks launched by the invisible creature, therefore the special ability surprise spells won't trigger by virtue of invisibility alone.

So to benefit from the special ability surprise spells, the arcane trickster can, for example, on the first round of combat cast a spell that has a *Target* entry at typical foes (like those without the extraordinary ability [uncanny dodge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue#TOC-Uncanny-Dodge-Ex-)) that have yet to act during that round. In such circumstances, the arcane trickster's special ability surprise spells usually triggers.

#### …And Paizo disagrees

Thanks to [Tyelor K](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/201007/8610) I learned that the FAQ includes [this exchange](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o2r):

> **How does the Surprise Spells class feature of the Arcane Trickster prestige class… work with spells like *magic missile* and *fireball*?**
>
> The Surprise Spells class feature allows the Arcane Trickster to add his sneak attack dice to spells that deal damage that target flat-footed foes. This damage is only applied once per spell. In the case of *fireball* this means it affects all targets in the area, with each getting a save to halve the damage (including the sneak attack damage). In the case of *magic missile*, the extra damage is only added once to one missile, chosen by the caster when the spell is cast.

Note that this exchange agrees that the "Surprise Spells class feature allows the Arcane Trickster to add his sneak attack dice to spells that deal damage **that target** flat-footed foes" (emphasis mine), yet then this exchange goes on to discuss *fireball* as if it were a targeted spell, even though it's not. If going by the FAQ, then, a player needs to ask the GM if each individual spell is eligible for surprise spells or not because *target* in that FAQ entry means something different from the game's normal definition of *target*.

Comment: I made a half orc caster with Precipice Strike to gain the flat footed condition more often, as there are shockingly few ways to force it on others. Your argument about the spell requiring a target does not make sense. Impromptu Sneak Attack makes sense since it requires an attack, but surprise spell is missing any references to Impromptu Sneak Attack, aiming, or anything else. Can you explain more in dept or clearer?

Comment: @Fering Like it says, "At 10th level, an arcane trickster can add her sneak attack damage to any spell that deals damage, if the **targets** [of that spell] are flat-footed." This means possibly dealing sneak attack damage with impromptu sneak attack when using *magic missile* or [*mass inflict light wounds*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/inflict-light-wounds/) (that's harder to get as an arcane caster but still) and not [*fireball*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball/) (because it lacks a *Target* entry completely).

Comment: Under the glossary and saving throws "Reflex (used to avoid effects that target an entire area, such as fireball)". So while the aiming spell info you linked to does have more support, I still feel like its wrong.

Comment: @Fering Honestly, I wish it were. Don't you think I know how awesome it'd be to sneak attack with a [*fireball*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball/)? `:-)` But I don't think the definition of Reflex saving throw can change what the Magic section actually says about a spell's *Target* entry, and area spells usually don't have *Target* entries (cf. [*quench*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/q/quench/)).

Comment: You can argue that fireball has to target the square it hits even if it is AC5

Comment: @Fering I don't think so? I mean, splash weapons and such have that requirement, right? But spells usually appear where the caster wants. Even *fireball* only requires an attack roll under special circumstances: "If you [the caster] attempt to send the [*fireball*] bead through a narrow passage, such as through an arrow slit, you must 'hit' the opening with a ranged touch attack, or else the bead strikes the barrier and detonates prematurely." (Success, in this case, counterintuitively means the caster gets the *fireball* bead through the opening, therefore "hitting" nothing.)

Comment: Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Answer (score 8):

[Surprise spells](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/prestigeClasses/arcaneTrickster.html#_surprise-spells) doesn't work with [black tentacles](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/black-tentacles/) at all.

> the tentacles use your caster level as **their** base attack bonus and receive a +4 bonus due to their Strength and a +1 size bonus.

Your character has sneak attack damage, your black tentacles do not. It's not you dealing damage, it's the black tentacles dealing damage. This is the same logic that applies to summoning monsters. If you summon a monster with the surprise spells ability, they don't get the sneak attack dice either.

Comment: Actually, thats a good point. I forgot that the BT got its own BAB

Comment: Actually that's not obvious at all that it works that way. If the PC was just a Rogue/Wizard with sneak of course she couldn't sneak on black tentacles, but here he got a feature that explicitly "add her sneak attack damage to any spell that deals damage".

Comment: There is a difference between causing damage and summoning / creating something that deals damage. The black tentacles spell has it's own stats, it doesn't matter that those stats are derived from yours. It's a separate entity.

Comment: @AnneAunyme I agree… sort of. I think that *absent* the phrase "if the targets are flat-footed" in the special ability surprise spells, the arcane trickster would just "add her sneak attack damage to any spell that deals damage" all the time, but just casting the spell *black tentacles* doesn't deal damage directly—the *effect* the spell *creates* does. However, upon typing that, that seems a *really fine* hair to split.

Comment: What if you summon an object dealing damage, not a creature? Is there still a difference? I don't know if it falls under the scope of the question, but it maybe can clear things.

Comment: @annoyingimp You mean like if an arcane trickster uses the spell *major creation* to bring forth something necessitating a hazmat team? I don't want to put words in Snappie's mouth, but it sounds like this answer would argue that the hazardous material's dealing the damage rather than the trickster, so no sneak attack damage would be dealt. I'm not sure where exactly this answer *draws* that line though.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Initially I was thinking about something like acid fog or icendiary cloud, but I think major creation does the job. And I think that line you mentioned is very interesting to figure out.

Comment: I feel that black tentacles and summon monsters are clear cut. Some other spells leave room for ambiguity.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I not not convinced either that the trickster would get sneak on black tentacles, I just think that Snappie's explanation is not enough to really decide on that. For example if you consider [Clashing Rocks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/clashing-rocks) it seems normal to me to apply sneak on it, even if technically you are creating the rocks and then the rocks hurt people.

Comment: Well, Clashing Rocks would apply sneak attack even without surprise spells, because 'you' make a ranged touch attack

Comment: So what about a fireball? You also just create it and then damages ensue, without needing an attack roll.

Comment: Yes, but the fireball doesn't have it's own stats. A summoned monster or black tentacles does have it's own stats. So the spell doesn't actually deal damage, it creates or summons a separate entity that does damage. And only the trickster has sneak attack, the monsters he/she summons do not.

Comment: and with [spike stones](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spike-stones/)? The stones don't have any stats so can you apply sneak attack?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I Can Chan's answer is somewhat wrong, the [Official Paizo FAQs](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o2r) indeed says that Fireball works with the Arcane Trickster's Surprise Spells. This FAQ was posted in 2011, so I'm not sure how it was overlooked for so long on this question/answer here... Hopefully this helps clear things up for anyone looking into this ability for their own groups.

I do tend to agree with Snappie that conjuration spells that literally create other things/monsters like Summon spells and Black Tentacles do not benefit from the Surprise Spells ability. Though it wouldn't be overpowered if they did considering Flat-Footed is a very specific condition that is generally only active on the first round of any combat until you take your action. There are only a few abilities to make enemies Flat-Footed after that, but they are usually somewhat niche and few and far between. I do believe by the strict ruling in the FAQ, and the wording of the Surprise Spells ability that Black Tentacles and Summoned monsters *would* actually gain the sneak attack damage from the Arcane Trickster, so long as that enemy had the Flat-Footed condition when the Black Tentacles/Summoned monster hit that enemy.

P.S. Sorry I wasn't able to post this as a comment either, I don't have enough reputation yet to comment as I only just started this account.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please, compose your own standalone answer to this question; there's no reason to reference other answers when you can write the right one! Thank you for participating and for helping strangers!