# Effective sneak attacks with spells

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature, sneak-attack

Update: Turns out there was an [FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qqm) in 2013 which states that spells like scorching ray only get sneak attack applied ONCE (or to one ray) instead of each ray getting the sneak attack. Due to this the build becomes basically worthless for what the goal was.End Update.

I am trying to build a caster who also does sneak attack damage with their spells. This is for a gestalt game but would like help on accomplishing it if it was normal.

The problems that I have encountered are:

- There are very few spells which have multiple ray attack rolls and deal lethal damage such as [Scorching Ray](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scorching-ray/) and [Contagious Flame](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contagious-flame/). I am trying to avoid spell/feat creation.
- To deal sneak attack you have a limited setting in which it can be used
- before they act in combat
- flanking (but ranged touch attacks dont benefit from flanking)
- sniping (which implies greater invisibility basically every combat)
- arcane trickster prestige class
- Sneak attack rules on spells a little vague, best examples come from arcane trickster.
- AoE spells normally cant benefit (arcane trickster can allow this)
- Single ray spells benefit once as expected
- no attack roll but multiple rays like magic missile only get one sneak attack applied even if each hits a different target
- Unclear how spells like Scorching Ray have it applied. Either each ray gets it or only one ray.
- DoT spells like [acid arrow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/acid-arrow/), is it applied only on the first hit or is it dealt each round?

So while its entirely possible to do sneak attack damage with spells, the rather small selection of multiple ray attacks and the restrictive conditions required to benefit from sneak attack makes it very challenging to use reliably.

My plan was to take [wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard) or [Arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist) on one side and [rogue](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue) (or something) on the other. The [arcane trickster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/arcane-trickster) while interesting, doesnt really help.

Comment: Related: ["What is required to be able to sneak attack with a spell or ranged attack?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45523)

Comment: @MikeQ Thanks, I didnt know about that question

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I think this would be a better question for this site once you have substantially more of your character complete.  Alternatively, you could ask if there are any notable builds that make use of spell-based sneak attacks, but I believe the answer to that is 'no'.  You could also ask what spell is best, offensively, for a gestalt Arcanist//full sneak attacker without Surprise Spells at each level, which would be an interesting question and I will ask that if you don't.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Go ahead and ask, clearly Im not asking this one correctly

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Did you ever ask that question?

Comment: @Fering Yes, but I never got a really great answer to it. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123479/whats-the-best-offensive-spell-at-each-level-for-a-arcanist-full-sneak-attacke?noredirect=1&lq=1 Specifically, I don't know if the posted answer is correct (it seems fine) because it doesn't back itself up like I would've liked, with discussions of how snowball et al are better and why and stuff.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil I remember this question now, mostly because of the increase in sneak attack damage