# How does sneak attack work with spellstrike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sneak-attack, touch-attacks, magus

If you hit someone with a sneak attack that has a touch spell on it would both instances of sneak attack go off or would just one?

Comment: Related: [What is required to be able to sneak attack with a spell or ranged attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45523/what-is-required-to-be-able-to-sneak-attack-with-a-spell-or-ranged-attack)

Answer (score 4):

When you use spellstrike, you *replace* the ordinary touch attack that you would get as part of the spell with a weapon attack. Since there is only one attack, sneak attack only applies once. Sneak attack requires a separate attack roll in order to deal its damage again.<sup>1</sup>

Note, however, that you can use spell combat to attack then also cast a spell. The attack can trigger sneak attack normally, of course. And then if that spell is a touch-attack spell, you can make another attack (with a weapon, or as a touch, as you like), and that would trigger sneak attack also. This works similarly to how two-weapon fighting does for a rogue; if all you really want is a way to fake Two-Weapon Fighting, the *arcane mark* cantrip is on the magus spell list and uses a touch attack—which allows you to use spell combat and then spellstrike at will.

(All of that assumes that each of these attacks *qualifies* for sneak attack—flanking is the easiest way to ensure that.)

1. <sub>There is *probably* an exception to this somewhere, but it’s going to be almost-always true.</sub>

Comment: so it doesnt add the damage to the spell then the normal sneak damage o well then thanks for the info

Comment: @austin Correct, the attack+spell combo only triggers sneak attack once.

Comment: A small point - Spell Combat allows the spell to be cast before or after the weapon attack/s. Therefore, when casting an offensive spell, it is almost universally better to cast it prior to attacking, allowing the weapon attacks to also incorporate the spell, if it either allows multiple 'detonations', or if the free attack misses. Doubly the case if Sneak Attack is also involved.

Comment: To clarify, if the spell requires an attack roll and deals damage, it can be used for Sneak Attacks. Shocking Grasp is fine, Ghoul Touch is not. Also, [FAQ reference](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qqm) about multiple simultaneous attack spells (Scorching Ray)